# Scala collections - partition with custom function

Tags: scala

Is there any function in `Scala` standard library for collections, that for collection of type `T` would return collection of collections of type `T`?

All the collections should have at most given number of "elements", the trick is, that different instances of `T` can have different "size" (that is why custom function is required, to return the "size" of `T`).

Answer (score 0):

I think `groupBy` would do the trick:

```
trait Sized {
  def size: Int
}

case class Foo(x: String) extends Sized {
  def size = x.length
}

case class Bar(x: Int) extends Sized {
  def size = x * 2
}

val list = List(Foo("a"), Foo("b"), Foo("aa"), Foo("bb"),
                Bar(0), Bar(1), Bar(2))

val grouped: Map[Int,List[Sized]] = list groupBy { _.size }
```

If you don't care about the sizes, and you just want a collection of collections, use `grouped.values`:

```
val groups: Iterable[List[Sized]] = grouped.values
```

Comment: It is not exactly what I wanted, here you will have buckets (size, listOfElementsWithGivenSize) and I want to get something like: List(List(a,b,c),List(d,e)) where a.size + b.size + c.size <= givenValue.

Comment: scala> val grouped = list.groupBy(_.size).values 
grouped: Iterable[List[Product with Serializable with Sized]] = MapLike(List(Foo(aa), Foo(bb), Bar(1)), List(Bar(2)), List(Foo(a), Foo(b)), List(Bar(0))